# Is it possible to cast to an Enum, when it is a Generic?

Tags: c#, enums

Trying to get a generic function like this to compile. The passed T is expected to be an Enum. Example is highly simplified :

```
    public T? GetEnumValue<T>(int id) where T: struct
    {
        // do some work to get the numerical value of the enum.
        // e.g. read number from a database, looking up by passed id. Fetched value could be null. 

        int? rawVal = 1;  

        // after work is done, return result as enum. 

        if (rawVal == null)
            return null; 
        
        return (T)rawVal.Value;  // Line XYZ : won't compile, as T is not an Enum at compile time.
    }
```

Example of use:

```
        SomeEnum? val = GetEnumValue<SomeEnum>(5);
        AnotherEnum? val2 = GetEnumValue<AnotherEnum>(3);
```

Where:

```
public enum SomeEnum 
{
    A,
    B,        
}

public enum AnotherEnum
{
    C,
    D,
}
```

Is there a workaround to get the line like that at XYZ to work?
This line is trying to convert the integral value of an enum, to an enum.
Assume in this case that GetEnumValue will only be called where T is an Enum, which has underlying integer values.

EDIT: one possible workaround might be:

```
 return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), rawVal.Value);
```

, which seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will compile:

```cs
return (T)(object)rawVal.Value;
```

You ought to add the extra constraint too though:

```cs
where T : struct, Enum
```

EDIT:

I will leave my original answer below for completeness but, after testing, I see that what I expected work did not work. It was not possible to cast a non-null value as type `T?`, even though I expected it would be. This is option will work, but it's debatable whether it is an improvement on the original or not:

```cs
return rawVal.HasValue
           ? (T)(object)rawVal.Value
           : (T?)null;
```

ORIGINAL (Bad advice):

You should also be able to get rid of your existing null check and do this:

```cs
return (T?)((object)rawVal ?? null);
```

or this:

```cs
return (T?)(object)(rawVal ?? null);
```

This will compile:

```cs
return (T?)(object)rawVal;
```

but it does generate a warning. I haven't tested to see whether it actually would throw the warned `InvalidCastException`. I don't think it would but, if you don't like warnings in your code, the preceding options will avoid that.

Comment: Tested, this `return (T?)((object)1 ?? null);` and this `return (T?)(1 as object ?? null);` would throw `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Nullable`, but this `return (T)((1 as object ?? null) ?? 0);` will work (?? 0 is the default value if int? is null).

Comment: thanks for the tip to use  "where T : struct, Enum". I had tried "where T: Enum", but it would not compile. So the key was to add both struct and Enum.

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman, you are correct. I have updated my answer to correct the record.

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman, thank you for fixing the variable name in the code I posted but the cast you removed is required. If you use `null` instead of `(T?)null` then it won't compile because the result of the `?:` operator is inferred to be type `T` and `null` cannot be implicitly converted to that type. This time I had already tested.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, It compiles on my side without an issue! ReSharper suggested to remove `(T?)` and it worked (netcoreapp3.1, C# 8.0).

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman, interesting. I used a .NET Framework project and it didn't compile, also using ReSharper.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXoha.png, I think it's about the language version (or ReSharper inspection configurations?)

Answer (score 2):

```
return (T?)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), rawVal.Value.ToString());
```

BTW, you can specify T to be Enum

```
public T? GetEnumValue<T>(int id) where T : Enum
{
   // ..
}
```

Comment: thanks, your Enum.Parse line does work, but it feels a bit "wrong" to have to convert the integral value to a string, and perform string parsing. 
But you gave me an idea to try the following, which worked: 
return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), rawVal.Value);

Comment: Glad it helped, `Int32` is overriding `.ToString()` in the first place, I think this usage is an example of where converting the integral value to a string is beneficial.